# Cant Access Variables Or Types From Project Headers Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, c++11, compiler-errors

I am not completely sure what is going on.  I logged onto my computer today and tried to compile my game code, but for some reason, everything had stopped working despite having worked the day before.  I didn't touch it and all the errors seem to be related to indexing my header files.

I have provided all the images I can to help provide some context for my issue.

[main.hpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRQyH.png)
[player.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHoI0.png)
[block.hpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TW97.png)

Also here is a pastebin containing the complete error log and a GitHub repository containing all of my code.

https://github.com/KangarooCoder/TSA-Video-Game-Sophmore-Year

https://pastebin.com/hwGzLw7R

```
CompileC /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Objects-normal-ubsan/x86_64/block.o /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Game' from project 'Game')
    cd /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.14 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize=enum,return,float-divide-by-zero,function,vptr -index-store-path /Users/ksbilodeau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game-gvfjrrwteiywkrbuhfwlprzuioif/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Game-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Game-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Game-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Game-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Debug/include -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Objects-normal-ubsan/x86_64/block.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Objects-normal-ubsan/x86_64/block.dia -c /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp -o /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/build/Game.build/Debug/Game.build/Objects-normal-ubsan/x86_64/block.o

In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/main.hpp:16:
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:49:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gMap'
    gMap.loadBlock(mRect.x / TILE_WIDTH, mRect.y / TILE_HEIGHT);
    ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:49:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TILE_WIDTH'
    gMap.loadBlock(mRect.x / TILE_WIDTH, mRect.y / TILE_HEIGHT);
                             ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:49:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TILE_HEIGHT'
    gMap.loadBlock(mRect.x / TILE_WIDTH, mRect.y / TILE_HEIGHT);
                                                   ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:113:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'camera'
    camera.x = mRect.x - (camera.w / 2);
    ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:113:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'camera'
    camera.x = mRect.x - (camera.w / 2);
                          ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:114:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'camera'
    camera.y = mRect.y - (camera.h / 2);
    ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/player.cpp:114:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'camera'
    camera.y = mRect.y - (camera.h / 2);
                          ^
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/main.hpp:17:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.hpp:16:
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.hpp:49:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BLOCK_WIDTH'
    std::array<std::array<KTile, BLOCK_WIDTH>, BLOCK_HEIGHT> mTiles;
                                 ^
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.hpp:49:46: error: expected a type
    std::array<std::array<KTile, BLOCK_WIDTH>, BLOCK_HEIGHT> mTiles;
                                             ^
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/main.hpp:17:
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.cpp:36:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gTile2'
        block.setDefaultTileType(gTile2);
                                 ^
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/main.hpp:17:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.hpp:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:798:41: error: binding value of type 'const pair<...>' to reference to type 'pair<...>' drops 'const' qualifier
    reference operator*() const {return __i_->__get_value();}
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/block.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/main.hpp:17:
/Users/ksbilodeau/Desktop/Projects/Game/Game/map.cpp:44:61: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::pair<int, int>, Block>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::pair<int, int>, Block>, void *> *, long> >::operator*' requested here
    for (std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, Block> &block : mBlockList)
                                                            ^
11 errors generated.
```

Comment: Consider putting copiable code snippets instead of images.

Comment: Add the exact error message. Add some more details about your question. It is not clear for now.

Comment: @arsdever I apologize for the vagueness of my post, I have updated it with accompanying code and error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it took a long time, but I believe I have discovered my problem.  I know the problem sprouted from including main.hpp in my other hpp files.  After removing it from all of my hpp files, I had to include main.hpp in all of my cpp files.  I believe I had to do this because the header guards were stopping me from circular inclusion, but I'm not completely sure.  Hopefully this helps anyone else who ends up stumbling upon the same problem as me!